# Find all possible values for the integral $\int_C \frac{\text{d}z}{zg(z)}$ where $C$ is NOT a closed curve and $g(z)$ is entire function.

Tags: complex-analysis

**Question**

Suppose $g(z)$ is an entire function that does not have zeros. What are all the possible values of integrals
\begin{equation} \int_C \frac{\text{d}z}{zg(z)} \end{equation}
where $C$ is any smooth curve that does not pass 0 and goes from $z=1$ to $z=z_0$.

**My thoughts**

This is a past exam question.

Firstly, since the function $\frac{1}{zg(z)}$ is holomorphic in some simply connected domains that contain $C$, this line integral does not depend on specific $C$. Then I am wondering how to understand the word 'possible' in the question.

If $g(z)$ is fixed, then I think this won't be an interesting question since we cannot get an explicit formula for the value of this integral (or if we can?).

If $g(z)$ is not fixed, then I can firstly take $g(z)$ be a constant other than $0$, then the integral can be any value other than $0$. So I think maybe I am supposed to prove that this integral cannot be $0$. But I don't know whether it is correct or how to do it.

Thanks for any comments and answers!

Comment: Define "pass $0$" Also, what/where is $z_0.$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Consider the case $g(z) = 1$, and $z_0 = 2$, which is about as simple as you can get. There's a straight-line integral, over a path $C_0$, whose value is $c = \ln 2 - \ln 1 = \ln 2$. But consider now an arc in polar coordinates: $C(t) = (r, \theta) = (1+t, 2\pi t)$, where $0 \le t \le 1$; what's the integral over THAT curve?  Hint: Look at $C$ followed by "going backwards along $C_0$"; that's a closed curve, and some theorem may help you evaluate the integral.

Once you understand this simple case, you'll know the answer to the problem overall.

Comment: The problem seems poorly worded to me. Is the OP asking for all possible values of

$$\int_C\frac{1}{zg(z)}\,dz,$$

where $g$ is allowed to be any entire function with no zeros, and $C$ is allowed to be any contour in $\mathbb C \setminus \{0\}?$